# little snitch turn off network monitor via apple script (remote login)

Tags: applescript

Hi i m trying to be able to stop/start Little snitche's network-monitor via the command line.

I tried to do this via applescript

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Little Snitch Configuration" to activate
    keystroke "," using {command down}
    click button "Monitor" of tab group 1
end tell
```

but it does not find the tab Monitor.

i tried using UIbrowser http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/ 
but this does not help ( not names).

any idea?
ideally i would like to use the script to ssh to a machine stop the monitor do some brew installs and then start the monitor again.

at this moment i m just killing the process

thanks for you help

i found some posts on the net from 2005 : snitchctl ...
but all download links are dead

Comment: for those wondering, you can prevent little snitch from reloading after killing process by unloading the launch agent with `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/at.obdev.littlesnitchd.plist`